# What should a reviewer do if an edit changes the possible close reason of a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62939/20058) has been recently edited by the owner and has now one reopen vote. I think that the question has now essentially become a duplicate of [this other one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49605/20058).

When reviewing the question, I left a comment pointing to the possible duplicate and suggested to leave it closed.

Probably such cases are rare, but I was wondering anyway what is the proper way to handle them.

1. Should one flag for moderator attention?
2. Should one vote to reopen and then, if reopened, vote to close as possible duplicate?
3. Should one post a comment and vote to leave it closed anyway?

Of course, I'd prefer a solution that allows the community to decide whether the question is duplicate or worth reopening.

Comment: Furthermore, third-party edits to posts which are closed/being closed and which either don't address the reason for closure or change from, e.g., "Unclear what you're asking" to "Too broad" should be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever." Accepting them just wastes people's time with the reopen vote.

Comment: Or maybe: 4. User should obtain golden tag badge for some of the tags in the question and then use [dupehammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/dupehammer/info) to immediately reopen and close as a duplicate. (More seriously, this is an option too, if the user who noticed the duplicate already has the necessary gold tag badge.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think yours is the most reasonable approach.

1. **Should one flag for moderator attention?** - There doesn't seem to be any specific moderator actions that needs to be taken here.
2. **Should one vote to reopen and then, if reopened, vote to close as possible duplicate?** - This requires more follow-up, for the dubious benefit of having another duplicate hanging around. Unless it's a *very* good duplicate (i.e. exceptionally well written and likely to come up in searches that could lead to the duplicate with answers) it doesn't seem worthwhile to go to all this trouble just to keep it as a duplicate.
3. **Should one post a comment and vote to leave it closed anyway?** - This is what I would do. The OP still gets to see the answers this way (since you have supplied a link to the duplicate).